# Trying to implement Mqtt 5.0 keepAlive feature - yet I still get disconnected by the Broker

Tags: mqtt, mqtt.js

I thought I would add `keepalive: 120` to my Mqtt Broker connection code, but I am still getting disconnected by the Broker with the following message (as per my Chrome Network tab):

`.M.K..HThe client was idle for too long without sending an MQTT control packet.`

For example

[image]

Here is the connection string in my `Angular 13` code (with `keepalive: 120`)

```js
    getBrokerConnection(): IMqttServiceOptions {
        const d = new Date();
        const tempId =
            'HarBrowser' + (d.getUTCMinutes() + d.getUTCMilliseconds() + Math.random()).toFixed(8).toString();
        const username = atob(this.config.getConfig('mqttUser'));
        const password = atob(this.config.getConfig('mqttPass'));
        const brokerAddr = this.config.getConfig('mqttBrokerAddress');
        const port = this.config.getConfig('mqttPort');
        const protocol = this.config.getConfig('mqttProtocol');
        return {
            hostname: brokerAddr,
            port: 8884,
            path: '/mqtt',
            clean: true, // CleanSession=true does not persist the prev client session
            connectTimeout: 30000,
            keepalive: 120,
            reconnectPeriod: 0, // 0 to disable auto-reconn (to prevent many front-end errors)
            clientId: tempId,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            protocol: protocol,
            connectOnCreate: false,
            protocolVersion: 5,
        };
    }
```

[image]
As I understood it, the `Mqtt client` is responsible for sending a `pingreq` to the broker in order to keep the connection alive (as per https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901045)

I do see this event logged to Chrome console many times, so I assumed it was my Mqtt client sending that `pingreq` as per the `keepalive` param:

```
 this.mqttService.onPacketsend.subscribe((res) => console.log(`onPacketsend event ${res}`));
```

Now am I supposed to programmatically send the `pingreq`, or is that supposed to be built into this Angular wrapper to `mqtt.js` ? I am a bit unclear as to what I am doing wrong, as I am getting disconnected by the broker.

** **UPDATE** **
In my backend Windows Service, it seems I can simulate the `keepalive` timeout issue if I set a break point and just let it sit there for a while. Otherwise it's not timing out on its own.
For example,

```
KeepAliveTimeout The client was idle for too long without sending an MQTT control packet.
```

I set a breakpoint here in my local deployment of the service (an Mqtt client):

[image]

Comment: That WebSocket message is not a MQTT message (there is no way to include a textual error message in the header like that), it must be coming from something in your backend and this is not a MQTT over WebSocket conenction (as that would be all that is possible from a web browser)

Comment: @hardillb I do have several mqtt clients running on multiple machines as a Windows Service. Perhaps as you said, one of them is "timing out" and then publishing that `idle for too long` message to one of my topics (which my browser app is subscribing to). I'll debug those services a bit further, thanks.

Comment: @hardillb if you see my screen shot (bottom of post), my browser does conn to `mqtt` via `wss`. Maybe there's something in my connection to the broker which allows that plain text situation.